# Did I build a source-follower amplifier? If not is there a common name for this circuit?

Tags: mosfet

[image: source-follower amplifier?]
[image]
The output over R2 produces this "saw tooth-ish" type wave over R2. I ask this question because I built an identical circuit using the same specifications as this circuit and it is not producing the same output over R2. It produces the same discharge effect but is completely square up to that point.

I want to gain a deeper understanding of what is going on with this circuit and was hoping if this had a common name I might be able to figure out what I am doing wrong with the physical circuit.

I will cite this page in my laboratory report as a source. Thank you for your time.

[image]

This is what the output of my physical circuit is producing. My intuition is telling me that somehow the right hand side is being shut off while the capacitor charges but I don't know why. I'm just trying to gain a deeper understanding of what I'm building.

net list:

```
 C:\Users\Epimetheus\Documents\Analog Circuits\Labs\Lab     
 5\Lab05_Schematic2.asc
 R1 N001 N002 1.2k
 R2 N004 0 1.2k
 C1 N004 0 1µ
 M1 N002 N003 N004 N004 MOD1
 V1 N001 0 12
 V2 N003 0 PULSE(0 5 0 0 0 5m 10m)
 .model NMOS NMOS
 .model PMOS PMOS
 .lib C:\PROGRA~2\LTC\LTSPIC~1\lib\cmp\standard.mos
 .MODEL MOD1 NMOS VTO=2.474 RS=1.68 RD=0.0 IS=1E-15 KP=20u
 +CGSO=23.5P CGDO=4.5P CBD=53.5P PB=1 LAMBDA=0
 .MODEL DIODE1 D IS=1.254E-13 N=1.0207 RS=0.222
 .ENDS 2N7000
 .tran 0 100m 0 0.001
 .backanno
 .end
```

Comment: Your simulation plot is showing a current waveform, not a voltage waveform.  Is that what you want? First, name your nodes so we can discuss the circuit conveniently. Then tell us which node you consider to be the output of this circuit. Then plot the voltage at the node you consider the output, rather than the current.

Comment: Also, what is the `.ENDS 2N7000` doing in there? Can you share the full netlist generated by LTSpice ('View SPICE Netlist')?

Comment: I added the netlist and the voltage plot. Sorry I meant to post that originally. I'll look into labeling the nodes now. I've never had to do that until now.

Comment: Something's wrong with your simulation if you're only getting 70 mV peak-peak output. Start trying to fix it by getting rid of the crap in the netlist that doesn't have to be there. The `.LIB` you're not using, the `.ENDS` that makes no sense, the `.MODEL`s you're not using.

Comment: Also try making the circuit with one of the FET models that comes with LTSpice, in case there's a model issue. There's no 2N7000 model built in but there is 2N7002, which is pretty similar.

Comment: Those were the specifications given for the lab assignment. I'll try using the 2N7002 and see what I get.

Comment: The possible issue is if you were given a model designed for PSpice (for example), it might not give correct results in LTSpice.

Comment: FWIW, I'm not sure you'll get a simulation result to match your experimental result. Are you sure R1 was in your experimental circuit in the same configuration and value as in your model?

Comment: Now that I think about it this makes a lot more sense. These were results many groups were getting so I the PSpice comment makes more sense. I'm quite certain the experimental circuit is the same configurations and values. I will post a picture tomorrow when I'm in my lab.

Comment: I didn't think to question the simulation because that was what was given but I see why that was a bad idea.

Comment: LTspice uses parentheses, and doesn't work right without them, memory serving. So NMOS(...) and not NMOS ... Not sure, though. I've always used the parentheses and recall having trouble copying models without them. Just a thought. Also, .ENDS is for .SUBCKT. I'd think it would be a problem, if unmatched.